# Video autoplay doesn't work in slider revolutioun plugin

Tags: plugins

The bottom line is that I have a video (with sound) that I added to slider revolution, autorun does not work when opening the site, it only works if you click on the play button

Comment: Third-party plugins are [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Nor would there be enough information here to diagnose a problem anyway :/ you'll need to go through Slider Revolution's official support routes.

Answer (score 0):

Slider Revolution may have some kind of workaround for this, but in general autoplay of un-muted videos is prevented at the browser level (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge). Usually you can get autoplay to work if the video is muted; but if you want both play + sound, the user must interact with the video.

Reach out to the makers of Slider Revolution if they offer autoplay of videos with sound and it's not working.